# Setting up GTKmm in Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, gtkmm

I am trying to create a GUI using GTKmm in Eclipse, however I can't get the configuration working.  For reference, here is my actual code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Gtk::Main kit(argc,argv);
    Gtk::Window frmMain;

    kit.run(frmMain);

    return 0;
}
```

These are the settings I have entered under the GCC C++ Compiler section.
All options:

```
-I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall
```

and for Command Line Pattern:

```
${COMMAND} `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS}
```

Finally, under the GCC G++ Linker section, I have this entered for the Command Line Pattern:

```
${COMMAND} `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs` ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} ${FLAGS}
```

Here is a link to my compile log:
http://pastebin.com/tfqv97w6

Comment: It looks like inserting `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs` in the command there is not enough to make this work. I do have a good solution for this give me a couple of minutes to get the info

Comment: I installed a plugin for eclipse that interfaces with pkg-config and allows you to select the pagkage from a list and hey-presto! https://code.google.com/p/pkg-config-support-for-eclipse-cdt/

Comment: @Galik Wow, that one speedy response.. take all the time you need :)

Comment: I added the plugin you suggested, and checked a few of the boxes that looked relevant, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: Did you put back the command line pattern to how it was before?

Comment: No, but let me try that now.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it a little bit, but it can't find glibmm.h http://pastebin.com/7YrJiNNn

Comment: Have you installed the development libraries for gtkmm-3.0? They are usual the same as the library package name with `-devel` or `-dev` appended to the end

Comment: Actually it looks like you didn't check the `glibmm-2.4` option in pkg-config.

Comment: The plugin you suggested doesn't seem to be working... I started adding the output from `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags` to the includes manually, and it seems to be fixing the errors I'm getting one at a time.  If you know of an easier way to to this, let me know.  Here is the latest output of the compiler btw.  http://pastebin.com/9142UxNQ

Answer (score 0):

I can't put this in the comments they are too restrictive. These are the steps I have just gone through to make a gtkmm program in my eclipse. I followed the procedure twice and it worked both times.

> **Create Project:**
>
> File -> New -> C++ Project
>
> Project Type: Executable -> Hellow World Gtkmm Project
>
> Toolchains: Linux GCC
>
> **Project Properties:**
>
> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Pkg-config -> gtkmm-3.0

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I performed two test.  One with your source instance and one with an instance from a simple file from the site.  Both worked flawlessly the first time using the steps below.

A Hello World example from the gtkmm website with Success:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/helloworld

First I installed the pkg-config Eclipse Plugin:
https://code.google.com/p/pkg-config-support-for-eclipse-cdt/

Then:

- Created a new empty C++ project in Eclipse
- Added three files to the project (`helloworld.cpp`, `helloworld.h`,
  `main.cc`)
- Added pkg-config-support to the project: [(right click on Project) -> Properties -> C++
  Build -> Settings -> Pkg-config -> (checkmark) gtkmm-3.0 -> OK
- From Eclipse I `Cleaned`, then  `Build all`, then was able to `Run` the
  example.

Answer (score 0):

I have a brief article about this (with screenshots), see it here:

http://www.hamedandobaideh.com/index.php/9-uncategorised/73-gtkmm-with-eclipse

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).