# Eclipse 3.8 won't see gtkmm.h

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gtkmm

I'm quite new to C++ and I aspire to learn gtkmm. I'm using linux mint 17.2 and Eclipse 3.8. When I enter:`#include <gtkmm.h>` the compiler will complain and give this error:

```
fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory
```

I've used synaptic and installed libgtkmm-3.0-dev and when I search for the header file `locate gtkmm.h` I get back the following path:

```
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h
```

So, now if enter to eclipse `#include gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h` I get a new error:  `fatal error: glibmm.h: No such file or directory`

```
locate glibmm.h
```

shows me this path:  `/usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h`.

So if I enter again: `#include <glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h>`

I get back the same error. fatal error: glibmm.h: No such file or directory

So what am I missing here ?

Comment: Do you mean #include <gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h>? You wrote #include gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm.h.

Comment: A yes.. sorry. It's a typo here, not in the code.

Comment: I don't know exactly how to tell Eclipse's build system where to find headers, though it should ideally involve pkg-config. But you should never put the gtkmm-3.0 part in the #include line of your C++ files. If your build system is working properly, a simple #include <gtkmm.h> is all you need.

Comment: The weird thing is that the same this happens with Code::Blocks (version 13.12)...  I'm getting the same error:  " fatal error: gtkmm.h: no such file or directory "     I'm using GNU compiler.   When you say involve pkg-config?

Comment: See the mention of pkg-config here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/ . pkg-config is a very popular way to get the compiler and linker options you need to use a library.

Comment: And this is probably a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079171/setting-up-gtkmm-in-eclipse-for-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I got it. in

`Project->Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings ->GCC C++ Compiler-> Miscellaneous`
you add
   `` `pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0` ``
in other flags.

In `GCC/C++ Linker`  on Miscellaneous section you add `` `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0` `` in other flags.

Now is GCC C++ Compiler again, on command line pattern you move the ${FLAGS} to the end.

It's working so far here.